# vCard converter

Tags: windows, vcard

I am looking for a program, preferably command line or web based, that will convert `.vcf` files.

Specifically, I am looking to convert

```
VCARD VERSION 2.1
```

To

```
VCARD VERSION 3.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Contacts](http://google.com/contacts) can import from vCard 2.1/3.0 and export
to vCard version 3.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use [convcard](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/convcard.1.html) (free, Linux, CLI). It is part of [msynctool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/msynctool.1.html), which is a CLI for [OpenSync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSync_(software)).

It converts a vCard version 2.1 in a vCard version 3.0 and vice  versa. By  default the source file format is autodetected, and is converted to the other format.

Comment: This needs to be a Windows solution, as listed in the tags.

Comment: @StevenPenny whoops sorry, I didn't see. I let the answer  in case it helps somebody else.